# Prove $\mathsf E^Y \mathsf E^Y [X] = \mathsf E^Y [X]$

Tags: statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

> Prove that$$\mathsf E^Y \mathsf E^Y [X] = \mathsf E^Y [X]$$ by using $$\mathsf E^{Y=y} [X] = \int x\,p(x\mid y)\operatorname d x$$ or $$E^{Y=y} [X] =\sum_x x\,p(x\mid y)$$

I am having trouble on where to start with this, I know that $\mathsf E X=\mathsf E\,\mathsf E^Y[X]$, but I am not sure how I can use what is being given to assist me.

Comment: This appears to be nonstandard notation for conditional expectation.

Answer (score 1):

In more conventional notation we wish to show: $\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)\mid Y)= \mathsf E(X\mid Y)$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)\mid Y) & = \mathsf E(\int x p(x\mid Y)\operatorname d x)\mid Y) \\[1ex] & \vdots & \textsf{what and why?} \\[1ex] & = \mathsf E(X\mid Y)\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E^Y \mathsf E^Y X & = \mathsf E^Y \int x p(x\mid Y)\operatorname d x) \\[1ex] & \vdots & \textsf{what and why?} \\[1ex] & = \mathsf E^Y X\end{align}$$

Fill in the blanks.

Comment: I understand what it equals, but i am not sure the steps to get to E(X|Y). Seems like it should be simple.

Comment: @Gregtt It is;  Let $g(Y) = \int x\,p(x\mid Y)\operatorname d x$ , then ask what is $\mathsf E(g(Y)\mid Y)$ ?